# How do I call use global variables in command line using (int argc, char *argv[])?

Tags: linux

I have a global variables
that want to call such that when I write `./file 5` on command line of linux terminal => will result in m =5

```
#define m

 ...
int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
 
m = atoi(argv[1]);
for(int i =0; i< m ; i++){
cout << "hello" << endl;
}
```

Comment: `#define m` should be `int m;`

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace `#define m` with `int m;` for it to work. `#define m` is a a preprocessor macro, not a global variable.